# QGIS Plugin works first time but QGIS crashes if executed second time

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, vector-layer

I built a QGIS plugin, in order to replace existing shapefiles by other temporary layers.
My script works the first time, but not the others. If I wait a little, script work again. I don't know why. Probably temporary links between my project and temporary layers.

I've tried for example with:

```
registryLayers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().keys()
legendLayers = [ layer.layerId() for layer in QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayers() ]
layersToRemove = set( registryLayers ) - set( legendLayers )
QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayers( list( layersToRemove ) )
```

But that doesn't work.

Here's my script :

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject
from qgis.core import QgsApplication
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFile
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterBoolean
from qgis.core import QgsVectorFileWriter
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QIcon
from time import sleep
import os

class Enregistrement(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

savepath = None
crois = None

def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
    
    project = QgsProject.instance()
    path = (project.fileName())
    m = (os.path.basename(path))
    path2 = path.replace(m, "Couche")
    
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFile('Savepath', 'Save Path', behavior=QgsProcessingParameterFile.Folder, fileFilter='Tous les fichiers (*.*)', defaultValue=path2))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterBoolean('Croisement', 'Croisement', optional=True, defaultValue=False))

def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):

    results = {}
    
    project = QgsProject.instance()
    root = project.layerTreeRoot()
    
    (parameter, self.savepath) = (parameters, parameters['Savepath'])
    (parameter, self.crois) = (parameters, parameters['Croisement'])
    
    if parameters['Croisement'] is True:   
        
        # Def save path of .shp and .qml
        pathcroiseq = os.path.join(parameters['Savepath'], "Pre-Etude - Equipements.shp")
        pathstyeq = pathcroiseq.replace('shp', 'qml')
        pathcroiscab = pathcroiseq.replace('Equipements', 'Cable')
        pathstycab = pathcroiscab.replace('shp', 'qml')
        pathcroisimb = pathcroiseq.replace('Equipements', 'Immeubles')
        pathstyimb = pathcroisimb.replace('shp', 'qml')
        pathcroissout = pathcroiseq.replace('Equipements', 'Souterrain')
        pathstysout = pathcroissout.replace('shp', 'qml')
        pathcoisaer = pathcroiseq.replace('Equipements', 'Aerien')
        pathstyaer = pathcoisaer.replace('shp', 'qml')
        
        #remove layers in layertree wich have the same names than new layer I want to save
        for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
            if layer.name().startswith('Pre-Etude'):
                root.removeLayer(layer)
                project.removeMapLayer(layer.id())
                sleep(0.25) 
            QApplication.processEvents()
        sleep(2)
        
        #save shp and qml at the save path
        layercroiseq = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Croisement - Pre-Etude - Equipements')[0]
        crs = layercroiseq.crs()
        crs.createFromId(2154)
        layercroiseq.setCrs(crs)
        QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layercroiseq, pathcroiseq, "UTF-8", layercroiseq.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile")
        layercroiseq.saveNamedStyle(pathstyeq)
        layercroiscab = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Croisement - Pre-Etude - Cable')[0]
        QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layercroiscab, pathcroiscab, "UTF-8", layercroiseq.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile")
        layercroiscab.saveNamedStyle(pathstycab)
        layercroisimb = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Croisement - Pre-Etude - Immeubles')[0]
        QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layercroisimb, pathcroisimb, "UTF-8", layercroiseq.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile")
        layercroisimb.saveNamedStyle(pathstyimb)
        layercroissout = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Croisement - Pre-Etude - Souterrain')[0]
        QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layercroissout, pathcroissout, "UTF-8", layercroiseq.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile")
        layercroissout.saveNamedStyle(pathstysout)
        layercroisaer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Croisement - Pre-Etude - Aerien')[0]
        QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layercroisaer, pathcoisaer, "UTF-8", layercroiseq.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile")
        layercroisaer.saveNamedStyle(pathstyaer)
    
    return results

def postProcessAlgorithm(self, context, feedback):
    
    results = {}
    
    project = QgsProject.instance()
    root = project.layerTreeRoot()
    grouppre = root.findGroup('Pre-Etude')
    
    if self.crois is True:
        
        # path of the saved layers
        pathpreeq = os.path.join(self.savepath,"Pre-Etude - Equipements.shp")  
        pathprecab = pathpreeq.replace('Equipements', 'Cable')
        pathpreze = pathpreeq.replace('Equipements', 'Zones d\'Eligibilite')
        pathprerem = pathpreeq.replace('Equipements', 'Remarques')
        pathpreimb = pathpreeq.replace('Equipements', 'Immeubles')
        pathpreres = pathpreeq.replace('Equipements', 'Reseaux')
        pathpresout = pathpreeq.replace('Equipements', 'Souterrain')
        pathpreaer = pathpreeq.replace('Equipements', 'Aerien')
        
        #remove layers in the layertree saved on ProcessAlgorithm
        for child in grouppre.children():
            
            project.removeMapLayer(child.layerId())
            QApplication.processEvents()
        
        #add to the layertree layers removed and layers saved on ProcessAlgorithm
        layerpreeq = QgsVectorLayer(pathpreeq, "Pre-Etude - Equipements", "ogr")
        project.addMapLayer(layerpreeq, False)
        grouppre.addLayer(layerpreeq)
        
        layerprecab = QgsVectorLayer(pathprecab, "Pre-Etude - Cable", "ogr")
        project.addMapLayer(layerprecab, False)
        grouppre.addLayer(layerprecab)
        
        layerpreze = QgsVectorLayer(pathpreze, "Pre-Etude - Zones d\'Eligibilite", "ogr")
        project.addMapLayer(layerpreze, False)
        grouppre.addLayer(layerpreze)
        
        layerprerem = QgsVectorLayer(pathprerem, "Pre-Etude - Remarques", "ogr")
        project.addMapLayer(layerprerem, False)
        grouppre.addLayer(layerprerem)
        
        layerpreimb = QgsVectorLayer(pathpreimb, "Pre-Etude - Immeubles", "ogr")
        project.addMapLayer(layerpreimb, False)
        grouppre.addLayer(layerpreimb)
        
        layerpreres = QgsVectorLayer(pathpreres, "Pre-Etude - Reseaux", "ogr")
        project.addMapLayer(layerpreres, False)
        grouppre.addLayer(layerpreres)
        
        layerpresout = QgsVectorLayer(pathpresout, "Pre-Etude - Souterrain", "ogr")
        project.addMapLayer(layerpresout, False)
        grouppre.addLayer(layerpresout)
        
        layerpreaer = QgsVectorLayer(pathpreaer, "Pre-Etude - Aerien", "ogr")
        project.addMapLayer(layerpreaer, False)
        grouppre.addLayer(layerpreaer)
    
    return results
```